# Numix removes borders and colors in unity launcher

Tags: unity, themes, gtk

I recently re-installed ubuntu 14.04, when i installed the numix gtk theme, the borders of all the icons in the unity launcher dissapeared along with the colors, i tried relogging, re-applying the theme, re-installing the theme and a lot more with ubuntu tweak and unity tweak tool. this wasn't the case before i re-installed.

[image]

Comment: I have this exact problem right now. The icon themes work fine, but the gtk theme isn't working. I'm just going to assume it's something wrong on their end. I'm just going to keep my theme as the default until they update it. Hopefully it gets fixed!

Comment: I also am having this problem. No borders for the launcher icons, and the indicator arrows are replaced with little rectangles.

Comment: ...they do look a lot better better without those borders and colors.

Answer (score 6):

The borders being removed was done intentionally in a recent update:

[Numix Project - Google+ - Numix GTK theme was updated along with Numix Light and Dark…](https://plus.google.com/+NumixprojectOrg/posts/SJkknCV2FDF)

Answer (score 6):

If you want them back, you just have to remove some files in the theme.
Browse to `/usr/share/themes/Numix/unity` (or wherever you put the theme). There you'll find some `.svg` files starting with `launcher_icon_` and then something. If you remove those files, you'll have your backgrounds back.

Answer (score 2):

This was apparently a design decision ("[we've decided against a glow and it is not coming back](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix/issues/153#issuecomment-55496012)") and [is discussed on github](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix/issues/153).

If you want to edit the style by yourself, have a look at the purpose of the different icons on the [unity theming guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the following files from `/usr/share/themes/Numix/unity` :

- launcher_icon_back_54.svg
- launcher_icon_back_150.svg
- launcher_icon_edge_54.svg
- launcher_icon_edge_150.svg
- launcher_icon_glow_62.svg
- launcher_icon_glow_200.svg
- launcher_icon_selected_back_54.svg
- launcher_icon_selected_back_150.svg
- launcher_icon_shadow_62.svg
- launcher_icon_shadow_200.svg
- launcher_icon_shine_54.svg
- launcher_icon_shine_150.svg

What I like to do is replacing them with those from the flat theme "Azure", which complement the Numix theme very well.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azure-gtk-theme
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Numix theme with Azure theme Unity tiles.]

Comment: I used your solution for the startup animation, looks awesome! http://i.imgur.com/uSiY2Ma.gif

Comment: Great idea, I'm copying this!